# How to retrieve view data in migration to controller?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, sql-view

I'm completely new to the views. I don't know how to get the view in controller. Below given is the view i have created using migration. I want to fetch the data in this view to my controller.  How to do that? Any help is appreciated.

```
 class CourseMarketView extends Migration
 {
     public function up()
        {
            DB::statement("
          CREATE VIEW course_market_view AS
          (
            SELECT 
    users.id,
    users.name,
    course.courseId,
    course.courseUniqueName,
    skills.id,
    skills.skill,
    subjects.id,
    subjects.subject
     FROM users 
      LEFT JOIN course ON course.courseId=users.id
      LEFT JOIN skills ON skills.id=users.id
      LEFT JOIN subjects ON subjects.id = users.id

          )
        ");
        }
  }
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\Skill;
use App\Models\Subject;

class CourseMarketController extends Controller
{
    public function getcoursebysubjectID(){

        $users = User::select("*")
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();             
        dd($users);    
    }
}
```

**course table**

```
Schema::create('course', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('courseId')->autoIncrement();
            $table->string('courseDisplayName');
            $table->string('courseUniqueName')->unique();
            $table->string('courseAddedBy');
            $table->dateTime('createdOn');
            $table->dateTime('lastUpdated');
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by creating new model like this :-

```
class CourseMarketView extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'course_market_view';
}
```

in controller you can do that :-

```
CourseMarketView::all();
```

Comment: Actullay this has a migration error that ,`column c.courseId doesnot exists` .Can u tell me what is wrong? I have id column of `course` table with the name `courseId`.

Comment: you have courseId column in courses table ?

Comment: Yes. `courseId` is the name of my id column(PK) in the course table.

Comment: can you update the question body with adding courses and uses migrations files ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the migration of `course` table.

Comment: The error is `PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column course.courseid does not exist at character 300
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "course.courseId".")`

Comment: Can u please see the code in the update dquestion?

Comment: first , i saw you change the pk  name from id to courseId , this is not good , follow laravel standard in database naming , you can change the pk to this : 
$table->id();
course migrations will work fine .
second thing , 
i saw you make join between course ( course id with user id ) this is not logic . 
you can make relationship between both by using course pk and user fk

Comment: like this 
"
          CREATE VIEW course_market_view AS
          (
            SELECT 
    users.id,
    users.name,
    course.courseId,
    course.courseUniqueName,
    skills.id,
    skills.skill,
    subjects.id,
    subjects.subject
     FROM users 
      LEFT JOIN course ON course.id =  users.courseId
          )
        "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235452/discussion-between-user16467258-and-mohamed-ahmed).